# List.FindAll don't returns a result set

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have next code. I'm reading from a text file, creating a list of Records (my structure).
Next I need to get all Records objects from the list where team's name equals team's name from text box on the form

```
Public Class Form1

    Structure Record

        Sub New(ByVal arr As String())
            Me.team = arr(0)
            Me.player = arr(1)
            Me.bats = CInt(arr(2))
            Me.hits = CInt(arr(3))
        End Sub
        Dim team As String
        Dim player As String
        Dim bats As Integer
        Dim hits As Integer
    End Structure

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        Dim team As String = txtTeam.Text
        Dim records As New List(Of Record)

        records.AddRange(
            From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("Baseball.txt")
            Select New Record(line.Split(","c))
            )

        records = records.FindAll(Function(record) record.team.Equals(team))

        Dim a As Integer = 1
        a += 1

    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that I received 0 records after

```
records = records.FindAll(Function(record) record.team.Equals(team))
```

Any suggestions?

P.S: This is for breakpoint

```
Dim a As Integer = 1
a += 1
```

Comment: Have you made sure that there is a record with the matching team text, you could have a case comparison problem with one in lower case and one in upper or partial

Comment: To add to what BobVale said - convert this into a foreach loop and see if you get the expected results. You may need to consider that `team` must be checked as case-sensitive text and/or whitespace.

Comment: There is no problems with case-sensitive text

Comment: Note that [`List.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.80).aspx) is _not_ Linq. It was even there at .NET 2 times. Maybe you have empty tokens. Try `line.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead. You should also use `Trim` in the constructor and `record.team.Equals(team, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, **I'm an idiot :)**

```
Structure Record
    Sub New(ByVal arr As String())
        Me.player = arr(0)
        Me.team = arr(1)
        Me.bats = CInt(arr(2))
        Me.hits = CInt(arr(3))
    End Sub
    Dim team As String
    Dim player As String
    Dim bats As Integer
    Dim hits As Integer
End Structure
```

I've made error in my structure. Mixed up the first two fields.
Thanks to all